# C++ Input CIN and pass to CMD

Tags: c++, cmd

Im trying to make a Shutdown timer with C++ and CMD.

Here's my code

```
int h;
int total;

cout << "Please enter in Hours" ;
cin >> h;

cout << "System shutdown in " << h << " hours";
h * 3600 = total;
system("shutdown /s /t XXXX");
```

I'm trying to pass total to the XXXX, how can I do this?

NOTE: This is just an example, I know this wouldnt work. But I got the full code working and compiled. I just wanted to know how system() can get any input from C++.

Comment: Before you get to the `system()` command, you need to get some working code done first. Remove the `system()` command completely, and try to compile this code, then figure out why it won't compile. only after you've figured out these preliminaries, then you can start figuring out how to implement the `system()` call.

Comment: Well, sorry, this isn't the full code, the full code works fine and compiled. That's just to see the ideas. :/

Comment: My actual question is how do you actually get system() to read the total int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`system()` call takes `const char *` as argument, so you need to build one.

```
total = h * 3600;  
string str = "shutdown /s /t " + std::to_string(total);
const char *cmd = str.c_str();
system(cmd);
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: I got a problem that to_string was not declared in this scope. I searched that it is the compiler problem, I'm using Dev C++. Advice?

Comment: @ShukriDamit you should try to google first. A simpe search for `std::to_string` gives [`Defined in header <string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: Dev C++ is the IDE, not compiler. The default gcc compiler included may be too old. Better use [mingw-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)

Comment: included the header <string>. Yeah I know it's an IDE, just thinking maybe the compiler is old because this software hasnt been updated since. Thanks btw for the advice!